# How to stop content from going under the footer

Tags: html, css

Hey all I have made a footer for my website but I seem to be getting a problem when I add a new container and say i set the height to 500px it over laps the footer at the bottom please check the image

[image]

My footer css

```
    .footer {
    height: 200px;
    border-top: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
}
.footer li {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
.footer h4 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -4em;
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 200px;
    clear: both;
}
.more-info {
    border-top: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
}
.more-info p {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h4>Links</h4>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="courses.html">Courses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="sign-up.html">Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="log-in.html">Log In</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h4>Social Media</h4>
                    <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Youtube</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because you have a negative bottom margin on your .wrapper. You can try changing it to:

```
 .wrapper {
   min-height: 100%;
   height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
```